# Como tratar exceptions com JTA?

Tags: java, jsf, jpa

Eu tenho um projeto onde estou utilizando JPA com JTA. No método `gravar`, eu coloquei a anotação `@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)` e nele existe uma chamada a um método de validação que pode lançar uma exceção chamada `ValidacaoException` que herda de `RuntimeException`.

Na documentação eu vi que quando a exceção é do tipo `RuntimeException`, o container irá fazer o *rollback* da transação. E no meu caso realmente está, só que este método `salvar` está sendo chamado dentro de um ManagedBean e no try/catch, a exceção que é capturada é a `TransactionalException` e esta não tem a mensagem que eu coloquei na validação.

Como eu faço para obter a mensagem original?

Abaixo segue os códigos. Classe `ContaServicoImpl`:

```
private void validarGravar(Conta conta) {
     List<String erros = new ArrayList<();
     if (conta.getDescricao() == null || conta.getDescricao().trim().length() < 3) {
         erros.add("Descrição é obrigatória ter ao menos 3 caracteres");
     }
     if (conta.getEmissao() == null) {
         erros.add("Emissão é obrigatória");
     }
     if (conta.getVencimento() == null) {
         erros.add("Vencimento é obrigatório");
     }
     if (conta.getEmissao() != null
             && conta.getVencimento() != null
             && conta.getVencimento().before(conta.getEmissao())) {
         erros.add("Vencimento tem que ser igual ou superior a data de emissão");
     }
     if (conta.getValor() == null) {
         conta.setValor(BigDecimal.ZERO);
     }
     if (conta.getValor().doubleValue() < 0.0) {
         erros.add("O valor não pode ser negativo");
     }
     if (conta.getSaldo().doubleValue() < 0.0) {
         erros.add("Total liquidado é superior ao valor da conta");
     }
     for (Liquidacao l : conta.getLiquidacoes()) {
         if (l.getLiquidacao().before(conta.getEmissao())) {
             erros.add("Existe(m) liquidação(ões) com data anterior a data de emissão da conta");
             break;
         }
     }
     if (!erros.isEmpty()) {
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Validação: \n");
         for (String s : erros) {
             sb.append(s).append("\n");
         }
         throw new ValidacaoException(sb.toString());
     }
 }

 @Override
 @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
 public void gravar(Conta conta, List<Liquidacao liquidacoesRemovidas) {
     validarGravar(conta);
     contaDao.gravar(conta);
     conta.getLiquidacoes().stream().forEach((l) - {
         liquidacaoDao.gravar(l);
     });
     liquidacoesRemovidas.stream().forEach(l - {
         liquidacaoDao.remover(l);
     });
 }
```

Classe `ContaEdicaoMB`:

```
public String gravar() {
     try {
         contaServico.gravar(conta, liquidacaoRemovidas);
         JsfUtil.mensagemInformacao("Gravado com sucesso", "Gravado com sucesso");
     } catch (TransactionalException ex) {
         JsfUtil.mensagemErro("Falha ao gravar", ex.getMessage());
         return null;
     }
     return "filtro?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

O Erro obtido:

```
Informações:   In REQUIRED TransactionalInterceptor
Informações:   Managed bean with Transactional annotation and TxType of REQUIRED called outside a transaction context.  Beginning a transaction...
Informações:   About to setRollbackOnly from @Transactional interceptor on transaction: JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=1 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[]
Informações:   Managed bean with Transactional annotation and TxType of REQUIRED encountered exception during commit {0}
javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:445)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:854)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.TransactionManagerHelper.commit(TransactionManagerHelper.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.cdi.transaction.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.transactional(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleInterceptorInvocation.java:74)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeAroundInvoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:84)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:79)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:68)
    at br.com.tebosoftware.financeiro.servico.ContaServicoImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.gravar(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.tebosoftware.financeiro.servico.ContaServicoImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.gravar(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.tebosoftware.financeiro.managedBean.conta.ContaEdicaoMB.gravar(ContaEdicaoMB.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```